# d3.js unique colors when plotting an arbitrary number of lines from an array of array of objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am plotting an arbitrary number of lines with the following code, where `allLines` is an array of arrays of objects such that each array of objects produces a line. Right now all the lines are the same color. **How can I make each one a unique color?** I am looking for an alternative that would not involve shoehorning this into useing `nest()`

```
   var lines = d3.select("svg").selectAll(".myLine")
        .data(allLines)

    lines.enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "myLine")
        .attr("d", tweetLine)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "darkred")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)

    lines.exit().remove();

    lines.attr("class", "myLine")
        .attr("d", tweetLine)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "darkred")
        .attr("stroke-width", 2)
```

Comment: You can use one of the [predefined scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for the recommendations but how would I do this? I am used to doing something like colors = d3.scale.category10() but then I am used to having to index colors myself (like colors[d.color]). I don't see how to translate that here where d3 is taking care of each line behind the scenes. I don't seem to have an available variable to index on to produce unique colors.

Comment: You just use it like any other scale, i.e. `colors(data1); colors(data2)`. It will produce different colours for different inputs.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff but how would I refer to data1 and data2? Right now I just pass an array of arrays, allLines.

Comment: You simply need `.attr("stroke", function(d) { return colors(d); })`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thank you for the clarification. However, this doesn't seem to work. It gives all lines the same color, I am guessing because the arrays have the same length whereas their values are different.

Comment: Oh right, then something like `.attr("stroke", function(d) { return colors(d3.sum(d, function(e) { return e.whateverTheNumberThatDeterminesTheLineIs; })); })` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also just learned that I can access individual elements of the data, so can also store it in a known location. But again, many thanks. Still struggling with d3, so this was quite helpful.

Comment: p.s. you don't want to put this in an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the [predefined scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10), e.g. `d3.scale.category20()`. You use it like any other D3 scale:

```
var colours = d3.scale.category20();
colours(someData);
colours(someOtherData);
```

For your lines, you have an array as the data, so that won't work directly. However, you can compute something based on the values for the lines and use that, e.g.

```
.attr("stroke", function(d) {
  return colors(d3.sum(d, function(e) {
    return e.whateverTheNumberThatDeterminesTheLineIs;
  }));
})
```